# Trying to replace a string on the fly, whats the best way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I am trying to replace some text on the fly by surrounding it with a span.

Example:

A person is typing, when they type the word "backwards" and his space after it, it makes the entire sentence or line with that word in it bold.

Right now I have a CSS class setup for it, and I have been trying to put it into a span, but I'm not sure that works... it also resets anytime something new happens, so the curser jumps back to the beginning and it doesn't let me advance.

Here is what I Have so far (my regex is wrong right now too):

```js
function replace(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    element = document.getElementById("script");
    rg = /^INT/;
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(
      rg,
      '<span id="bold">$1</span>'
    );
  };
};
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="script" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;" onkeydown="replace(event)">
  Replace
</div>
```

Comment: Your regex looks for INT at the beginning of the string due to `^`. Capture INT by wrapping it in brackets. Your replace function now only fires after a return. This is intentional?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Mouser, your regEx will look for **INT** string at the beginning.

Here is the correct code. You just need to fix your RegEx according to your need. I have tested it and its working.

```
function replace(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    element = document.getElementById("script");
    var _str = element.innerHTML.trim("")
    rg = /INT/;
    element.innerHTML = _str.replace(
      rg,
      function($1) {
        console.log($1)
          return '<h1><span id="bold">' + $1 + '</span></h1>'
      } 
    );

    //Set cursor position
    var range = document.createRange()
    var _lastDom = element.childNodes[element.childNodes.length - 1];
    var end = '';
    if(_lastDom && _lastDom.innerHTML == undefined) {
        end = _lastDom.length
    } else {
        _lastDom
        end = 1
    }
    range.setStart(_lastDom,end)
    range.setEnd(_lastDom,end)
    sel = document.getSelection()
    sel.removeAllRanges()
    sel.addRange(range)
  };
};
```

Comment: $1 is correct in original code. This will generate errors @HarpreetSingh

Comment: Anonymous function in replace is unnecessary: `'<h1><span id="bold">$1</span></h1>'` should be sufficient as replacement string.

Comment: @Mouser, actually I am not familiar with that method

Answer (score 0):

probably a way better way to do it, but something like this might help

```js
var thepara=document.getElementById('thepara').innerHTML;

document.getElementById('thetext').addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
 var thetext=this.value;
 var thelength=this.value.length;
 
  var thestart=thepara.indexOf(thetext);
  var found=thepara.substr(thestart,thelength);
  if(found != "n" ){
    var newstring="<span class='bolded'>"+found+"</span>";
      document.getElementById('thepara').innerHTML=thepara.replace(found,newstring);
  }
  });
```

```css
.bolded{font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="thetext" />
<div id="thepara">It was a nice sunny day in the suburbs of South East London</div>
```